# remove attributes from all objects

Tags: json.net

I am looking for the easiest way to remove attributes from every class (i.e: created / modified dates and the like) - without having to specify a customer converter on every one of our domain classes.

Additionally - I don't want to do it under normal course - but only when I enable our test case recording feature - so really I need two sets of serialization attributes, one for normal course and one for tests (hence the reason to remove the dates, because they change and I cannot determine if the results are correct).

I have not looked at the source code yet and was hoping to avoid that because I expect it will take me a while to get up to speed on it and was hoping that you could do this through the serialization settings somehow.

Thanks in advance.

Whatty

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer elsewhere - it can be found at [Sample ContractResolver that conditionally removes properties from JSON.](https://gist.github.com/gpltaylor/33b5e6056c1d59e83b1a)

Comment: Hi Whatty, please take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers), SO should be a be a reliable source for Q/A.